# Postfix configuration on an Ubuntu Server LAMP cluster

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, cluster

I currently have a Postfix/Dovecot installation on a web server running Ubuntu Server, and have virtual alias rules that push emails that would be delivered locally into Dovecot. I have a reverse DNS/PTR record that matches 'myhostname', and everything works as expected. I pick up emails generated by Logcheck and Tripwire via Dovecot, and emails sent via PHP work OK.

I'd like to expand this setup to cope with four new servers on the same LAN (two software load balancers, two web servers), and allow emails from Logcheck and Tripwire from the new servers to be pushed into the Dovecot mailbox on the existing one. Is this a case of:

. Installing Postfix on all new machines.

. Setting 'fake' addresses in 'myhostname', i.e. server1.mydomain.com.

. Adding the IPs of all machines into 'mynetworks' on the original box.

. Adding virtual alias rules on each machine to match those on the existing box.

or am I overthinking this? I'm assuming that I need multiple Postfixes, both to prevent messages delivered to root on each machine being delivered locally and to ensure PHPs mail() function works. Is this the case? Should I be concerned about not have PTR records and fake FQDNs for the new machines? Is there a better way of getting the functionality I'm after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure postfix on each of additional servers as [Null Client](http://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html#null_client)

Comment: Cheers Alex. That works perfectly. Am I right in thinking that /etc/aliases is *only used* for local mail delivery, so is redundant in either a wholly virtual transport or null client configuration?